# How to update plain .js file in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a filename.config.js file with contents like these:

```
module.exports = {
    foo: [
        {bar: "bar"},
    ],
};
```

Does the native Node.js or some lib for it have any tools that can add another item to `foo` without resorting to regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself in some googled schematics:

```
const { cosmiconfigSync } = require('cosmiconfig');

export function getConfig(path?: string): MyConfig {
  const explorer = cosmiconfigSync('filename');
  if (path) {
    path = `${process.cwd()}/${path}`;
  }
  const configSearch = explorer.search(path);

  return configSearch ? configSearch.config : {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.json` file for configurations. Never dynamically write to a `js` file.

filename.config.json

```
{
    "foo": [
        {"bar": "bar"},
    ],
}
```

Then in another js file you can read the file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const config = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './filename.config.json'), 'utf8')
);

console.log(config);
```

To edit the file, you can edit the object and write it back to the file:

```
config.biz = 'baz';

fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './filename.config.json'), JSON.stringify(config));
```

`JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` can be used to convert JSON objects from a string to a real object and back. No regex required.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need to utilize a config from another framework. I have no option to use a JSON. This does not answer my question